# Android Back Button Pressed Check

Tags: android, view, toast, back

So I'm currently developing a turn based game app. And it displays toasts from a view on who's turn it is after each turn is taken. What's weird though, is if I hit the back button it will go back to the main menu(previous activity) but the toasts will still linger till they time out. Also if I hit back twice and it goes to the home screen, the toasts will still show until they finish. I want to implement a check or some way to cancel those toasts when the back button is pressed. I have to do this in my view too, my view contains all the toasts and all the code to the game, the gameActivity only has onCreate to create the view for the game. Any ideas?

Comment: have you looked at using [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) yet?

Comment: Yes I tried using this it works an exits the activity to the previous one, the problem is I can't make it so the toasts get killed, instead the linger, even if you back twice to home.

Comment: so cancel your Toasts in your onBackPressed() method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your Activity you have override method:

```java
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // do something
        yourView.notifyBackPressed();
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

And in your View you have to implement method, for example `notifyBackPressed()`.

Comment: public notifyBackPressed(){  myToast.cancel(); }

Comment: Of course Toast myToast = new Toast(YourActivity.this); must be defined globaly in your View.

Comment: Didn't work just crashes when the backbutton is pressed. The problem is you cannot just do "yourView.notifyBackPressed()" in the activity without making the toasts and notifyBackPressed static and or creating a new instance of the view in the onKeyDown method which just crashes the activity.

Comment: My solution works in my projects. Show me your code.

Comment: It does work the problem I have is that their maybe 1 of 6 toasts showing so when I break it down to the first one it does cancel the toast on the backPressed. However, I have to account for all and when I have all the .cancels listed in the onBackPressed method I get nullpointer exceptions for the ones that are not there and I cannot fix this issue.

Comment: I got this to work by initializing them global as null, then when the toasts needs to be created I would overwrite it. So my onBackPressed has null checks and THEN cancels the toasts if they are NOT null. Now the toasts actually get canceled when back is hit AND I get no null pointer exceptions. Thank you so much this does work!

Comment: Sorry last thing, so I want to also implement this for the home button because the toasts still appear on the home screen after it is pressed, I tried the exact same functionality but it still doesn't work. I just added another if block in the activity onKeyDown, I also tried removing the backbutton part and JUST doing the home button to see if it would work but it goes home and the toasts still linger. DO you have any experience with this? I tried implementing the exact same way I did onBackPressed....

Comment: Yes HOME button doesn't work the same way as BACK button, but you can call your method yourView.notifyBackPressed(); - on onPause() of Activity.

Comment: Ah perfect worked like a charm thanks buddy for all your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

1. Try to use **Toast.LENGTH_SHORT** or
2. You should set duration (milliseconds) for custom Toast like this.

   **Custom toast:**

   ```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
       View layoutToast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_layout,
               (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toastcustom));

       ((TextView) layoutToast.findViewById(R.id.texttoast)).setText("I'm custom toast");
       final Toast myToast = new Toast(
               (EmployerNominationView) getActivity());
       myToast.setView(layoutToast);
       myToast.setDuration(300);
       myToast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 45);
       myToast.show();
       Handler handler = new Handler();
       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               myToast.cancel();
           }
       }, 1000);
   ```

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I need my toasts long for the game to appear properly, I use handlers to have the bots take longer with their turns so my toasts have LENGTH.LONG to match up with the timing it takes the bot to play. So it appears as if he is thinking and it will say, "Bot's turn..." Then the toast duration ends perfectly for when the bot makes his move. If I shorten it, the bot plays too fast. I don't wanna change my toasts around. I wanted to try and just have an onBackButton pressed check after the toasts, so while it is showing, if that button is pressed it will cancel the toast.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate Toast

   ```
   Toast toast;
   toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Messages", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
   toast.show();
   ```
2. Cancel the Toast you may use onKeyDown() or onBackPressed() .

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

       toast.cancel();
       return true;
   }

   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   ```

   }

Comment: Tried this everything runs fine but the toasts still linger after back is touched.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try with making Toast Global and cancel the toast on Back Pr 
Toast mToast = new Toast(ApplicationContext);

public void onBackPressed(){
    mToast.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Tried this in multiple aspects, still doesn't kill the lingering toasts on back.

Comment: If this is still not working then try to make your own toast, using Alert dialog

Answer (score 0):

I found this and will hellp you
**[Android AppMsg (Crouton) Library](http://androidlibs.org/androiduiviews)**
Implementation of in-layout notifications. Based on Toast notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I try the below method to detect the back button pressed on the action bar in activity by the first method and the second one is used to detecting the mobile hardware button back or kill activity button.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```